# How to define an enum type which includes a templated parameter ( C++ )

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I would like to define a type T as an enum which can take values {A, B, C, S1, ..., Sk} but since k is a compile-time variable I can't just type that.

```
template <size_t k>
struct T {
   enum class {
      A, B, C, S_1, ..., S_k
   };
};
```

How can I define the type?

Comment: How do you intend to be able to refer to the enumerators if you don't know how many there are? Why is an integer type not sufficient for your use case?

Comment: Enums are compile type replacements; class enums only add type checking but there are otherwise identical. There are no variables and no ranges at run time. Therefore, you can't use them like a vector.

Comment: Answer1: I know how many there are when I am using them. Just not when I am defining the type.

Answer2: I would like it to be clear at compile time. The same reason we use enum instead of int.

Maybe an example would help to clarify it. 
Say T is the location of a robot which can be at location A, B, C or one of k other points and I define a run time variable "v" based on that. So in the code, I can see where the robot is going to.

Comment: But when would you actually type a name like `S_19`? Wouldn't the "other points" need to be referenced by numeric variables to do much useful with them?

Comment: You are right I can never write S_19, but how can I show that these are all "locations"? 
Are there any alternatives to enum that can clarify this in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not with an `enum` but it gives a very similar syntax (requires C++14 or higher):

```
template<size_t k>
struct T {
    struct MyEnum {
        static constexpr int A = 0;
        static constexpr int B = 1;
        static constexpr int C = 2;
        template<size_t n,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<n != 0 && n <= k>::type>
        static constexpr int S = Enum::C + n;
    };
};
```

And to access:

```
 int test1 = T<2>::MyEnum::A;
 int test2 = T<2>::MyEnum::S<2>; // Equivalent to S_2
 int test3 = T<2>::MyEnum::S<3>; // Compile error: 3 > 2
 int test4 = T<2>::MyEnum::S<0>; // Compile error: 0 < 1
```

The syntax is similar except for the angle brackets and will all be computed at compile so no run time overhead.

If you want these to return an `enum` you can always define your own and swap `int` for your `enum` (the downside being you can't name the `struct` and the `enum` the same name ofcourse).

Comment: This looks fine. the only issue is when accessing it there is some redundancy when you have to type T and enum. I would only need one of them to declare what the type is. Is there a reason I can't omit T and just use MyEnum ?

Comment: @Milad yes its possible to omit `T` but only if `MyEnum` is accessible otherwise, for example within `struct T`'s declaration you can just type `MyEnum::B` without the `T<...>`. The rules are the same for an enum class, you would still need the `T<...>::` if accessing the enum from outside, but not from within, the declaration of `T`

Comment: @Milad I see you are new so I will remind you that if this answered the question then you should mark it as the answer so it doesn't show in the unanswered tab (plus internet points are always nice :) )